# Bibtex entry without author starts with : when using lncs bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, urls, lncs

I have a reference without an author:

```
@misc{abcd,
   title = {{The abcd Project}},
   howpublished = "\url{http://abcd.org/}",
   note = "[Online; accessed 21-January-2015]"
}
```

In lncs format, the reference comes out as (if this is reference number 9)

9. : The abcd Project. http://abcd.org/ [Online; accessed 21-January-2015].

How can I remove the ':' preceding the title?

Answer (score 2):

You can update to the latest version of lncs format ([version 2.19, from 31-Mar-2014](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/)), which fixes this problem.